# How to handle patternTransform using ng-attr? (keep it camelcased)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, attributes

I have a template which contains this SVG element

```
<pattern ng-attr-patternTransform="translate({{ example }}, 0)" etc >…</pattern>
```

which produces this:

```
<pattern ng-attr-patterntransform="translate({{ example }}, 0)" patterntransform="translate(-45, 0)" etc >…</pattern>
```

How can I preserve the name camelcased?

I also tried using an alternative syntax

```
ng-attr="'patternTransform=translate({{ example }}, 0)'"
```

to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Since version 1.3.7](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d8e37078600089839f82f0e84022f1087e1fd3f2), AngularJS supports camelcased attributes. You just need to prefix the uppercased letters with an underscore.

```
ng-attr-pattern_transform=""
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, angularjs doesn't support the case-sensitive attribute yet. But there are attempts to make it works especially for SVG. Please see [#1925](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1925) for a discussion.

As a workaround, you could write a custom directive to preserve the attribute case as suggested by @stanleygu in this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1925#issuecomment-36087671).

```
.directive('caseSensitive', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.attr = attr;
      var caseSensitive = attr.caseSensitive.split(',');
      angular.forEach(caseSensitive, function(a) {
        var lowercase = a.toLowerCase();
        scope.$watch('attr[lowercase]', function() {
          element[0].setAttribute(a, element[0].getAttribute(lowercase));
        });
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Then use it like this:

```
<pattern case-sensitive="patternTransform" ng-attr-patternTransform="translate({{ example }}, 0)" etc >…</pattern>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wish someone could come up with something better.

Comment: Me too :(  There may be a third-party directive that do it better.